# How to increment all numbers of a string and insert every of them after every actual number?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

How can I append incremented numbers to the old ones in Python.
I have a string and a regular expression to find all of its numbers, but when it comes to the task, it doesn't work well.

Here's what I mean:

"This string contains numbers: 4401 4402 4448" -> "This string contains numbers: 4401 4402 4402 4403 4448 4449"

Here's the regular expression if it helps:

```
regex = '(\S\d+[^\\^.^a-z^A-Z])'
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#re.sub).

```
import re

line = "This string contains numbers: 4401 4402 4448"
line = re.sub(
    '\d+',
    lambda m: '{} {}'.format(m.group(), int(m.group())+1),
    line)

assert line == "This string contains numbers: 4401 4402 4402 4403 4448 4449"
```

Comment: This is exactly what i need. Thanks a lot!